# AGE function causing the following error: ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables

Tags: amazon-redshift

I do not understand why I am getting this error. Seems like a simple query.

```
select *,age(last_order,first_order_date) from
(
    select organization,first_order_date::date, max(delivery_date::date) as last_order
    from [orderdetailreport]
    group by organization,first_order_date::date
)a
```

Answer (score 0):

The `AGE()` function is not supported for queries on user data.

More info here: ["Leader Node–Only Functions"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_SQL_functions_leader_node_only.html)